# d3 dynamic url based on array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, dynamic-url

I'm trying to append image urls to an SVG element using D3. I've tried various codes including this one.

```
svg.append('g')
.selectAll('image')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('image')
.attr('class', 'countryflag')
.attr('href', `https://www.musiktrends.com/images/countryflags/`

+ 
data.map(yValues)
+
`.png`)

.attr('width', 50)
.attr('height', barHeight)
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', yPos)
.attr(`transform', `translate(5,`+0+`)`)
;
```

The problem with this code is that I get all countries in the url. I only want the country that corresponds to each value in the json array.

Here's the data array:

```
data = d3.json('data.json')
.then(data => {data
.forEach(d => {
d.country = d.country;
d.population = +d.population * 1000;
});
render(data);
});
```

I've tried writing a function as well but because I'm fairly new at this I couldn't figure it out. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To build the flag URL, you're mapping the function `yValues` on the `data` array. Can you show what it is doing?

If you want an URL *pre* country, you should not use `.map` in the URL building but rather do a loop around the whole `svg. ...` call.

Also, note that on `` .attr(`transform', `translate(5,`+0+`)`) ``, you're using different type of quotes around `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Moutah. This is what I ended up doing and it seems to work fine:

Data:

```
data = d3.json('data.json')
.then(data => {data
.forEach(d => {
    d.country = d.country;
  d.population = +d.population * 1000;
  d.flagurl = `../images/countryflags/`+d.country+`.png`;
});

console.log(data);
render(data);
});

const yPos = d => yScale(yValues(d));
```

Image

```
svg.append('g')
.selectAll('image')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('image')
.attr('class', 'countryflag')

.attr('href', d => (d.flagurl))

.attr('width', 50)
.attr('height', 0.8*barHeight)
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', yPos)
.attr('opacity', 0)
.attr('transform', `translate(`+0.05*barHeight+`,`+0.1*barHeight+`)`)

// transition and delay         
.transition()
//.attr ('y', yPos)
.attr ('opacity', 1)
//.attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())

.duration(animateDuration-625)
.delay(delay+animateDuration+375)
;
```